# Referencing JSON object to filter with jQuery.grep()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, grep

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496439/how-to-filter-a-multi-dimension-json-object-with-jquery-grep), in which the accepted answer includes a JS Fiddle, I was able to verify that I can filter my data using [jQuery.grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/). However, I am not able to replicate the effect using output from my server. I suspect I am overlooking something obvious in the object referencing, but being new to JavaScript I think I need someone to point it out for me.

This is my data output, an array of objects:

```
[{"id":"3","src":"url1","category":"A"},
{"id":"32","src":"url2","category":"D"},
{"id":"38","src":"url3","category":"E"},
{"id":"39","src":"url4","category":"E"},
{"id":"42","src":"url5","category":"F"},
{"id":"49","src":"url6","category":"B"},
{"id":"44","src":"url7","category":"F"}]
```

I use the following code to filter entries within category F:

```js
var obj = [{"id":"3","src":"url1","category":"A"},
{"id":"32","src":"url2","category":"D"},
{"id":"38","src":"url3","category":"E"},
{"id":"39","src":"url4","category":"E"},
{"id":"42","src":"url5","category":"F"},
{"id":"49","src":"url6","category":"B"},
{"id":"44","src":"url7","category":"F"}];

obj = $.grep(obj, function(element, index){
  return element.category == "F" // keep elements in category F
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is my Ajax call to the server:

```
var obj = $.post( url, {term: term }, function(data){
}, 'json'
);
```

When performing `console.log(obj);` I find my data output as an Object in the console, but can't seem to get to it. For the grep function to work, I need to access the output as an array of objects. It is there, waiting for me, but how do I reference it?

Comment: The result of `grep` is an array of objects. [MDN Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements)

Comment: Always use triple equals (===) when doing string comparisons.

Comment: @Samuel, why === and not ==? Both seem to work in my case

Comment: It is a best practice, where === also does type checking and is therefore more predictable. Here is some more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
var obj = $.post( url, {term: term }, function(data){
}, 'json');
```

`obj` is a promise not the response data

You need to access the response data inside the success callback

```
$.post( url, {term: term }, function(data){
    var obj = $.grep(data, function(element, index){
        return element.category == "F" // keep elements in category F
    });
    console.log(obj);    
}, 'json' );
```

Comment: remember that ajax is asynchronous

Comment: Could you please elaborate? What are the implications of asynchronous calls in this case?

Comment: Best explained in this tutorial type answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call